# Correct way to scailing aws ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

Now I'm architecting AWS ECS infrastructure.

To auto scale in/out, I used auto scailing.

My system is running on AWS ECS(to deploy docker-compose)

Assume that we have `1 cluster`, `1 service` with `2 ec2 instance`.

I defined scailing policy via `CloudWatch` if cpu utilization up to 50%.

To autoscailing, we have to apply our policy to `ecs service` and `autoscailing group`.

When attach cloudwatch policy to `ecs service`, it will automatically increase `task definition` count if cpu utilization up to 50%.

When attach cloudwatch policy to `autoscailing group`, it will automatically increase `ec2 instance` count if cpu utilization up to 50%.

After tested it, everything works fine.

But in my `service` event logs, errors appear like this.

`service v1 was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 8bdf994d-9f73-42ec-8299-04b0c5e7fdd3 has insufficient memory available.`

I think it occured because of service scailing is start before ec2 instance scailing. (Because service scailing(scale in/out task definition) need to ec2 instance to run it)

But it works fine. Maybe it retry automatically about several times. (I'm not sure)

I wonder that, it is normal configuration on AWS ECS autoscailing?

Or, any missing point in my flow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECS can only schedule a service if a container instance is available that matches the containers cpu/memory requirements. Ensure you have this space available to guarantee smooth auto-scaling.

The ec2-asg scaling should happen before service auto-scaling to ensure container instance is available for task scheduler.

Comment: It means that I have launch extra instance for service always? According your opinion, It will scale in/out smoothly. But always waste a resourece. (Because of extra instance) is it a best way?

Comment: Not always. If you have cpu/mem available in existing instance, you can get away with that.

Comment: Which instance type are you using ? What are your container mem/cpu limits ?

Comment: c4.large. Maybe it is known issue. Please refer it -> https://engineering.depop.com/ahead-of-time-scheduling-on-ecs-ec2-d4ef124b1d9e

Comment: This is not an issue per se but the current behavior of ecs. The service/container auto scaling is not tied with asg/ec2-scaling. So for the service scale out to happen, one's architecture should ensure there exists ec2-instances with cpu/mem requirements of the container.